# How to dynamically add <!--nextpage--> to a wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic

I am after adding dynamically the `<--nextpage-->` tag only on mobile, to posts.
It appears that hooking to `the_content` is too late, as `nextpage` is being decided on "the_post()" phase.

I found some code that would do that on "the_content", but, at `the_post` phase, `$content` is not available for manipulation.

I would really appreciate if you could write the relevant php code to hook/filter the right phase and be able to dynamically insert the `<--nextpage-->` on posts that are viewed on mobile.

I'm using wordpress + thesis2, editing custom.php for hooks/filters/functions.

Thank you in advance,

Ronen.

Comment: Here's the answer... http://www.byobwebsite.com/forum/general-thesis-questions/how-to-continue-reading-in-a-post-on-mobile-only/#p24251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

http://www.byobwebsite.com/forum/general-thesis-questions/how-to-continue-reading-in-a-post-on-mobile-only/#p24251

You'll find in the above link the code to use.
R.